# chef recipe - how to add a timeout to ::File.exists? in ruby_block

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Consider this code:

```
ruby_block 'wait for tomcat' do
  block do
    true until ::File.exists?('/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/system/WEB-INF')
  end
end
```

How can I add a `timeout`, so that in the case that the deployment went wrong (and the file will never exist), my recipe can continue (and fail) after (say) 30 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using ruby (untested, I may have forgot something there):

```
ruby_block 'wait for tomcat' do
  block do
    iter=0
    until ::File.exists?('/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/system/WEB-INF') || iter > 5 do
      sleep 6
      iter++
    end
    raise "Timeout waiting for tomcat startup" unless iter <= 5
  end
end
```

But this kind of construct usually means you're falling into the converge  vs compile problem. and thus you're probably trying to solve an XY problem. As the tomcat may not start before the end of the run anyway.

TL;DR: you're trying to code a state change instead of describing a resulting state, this goes against Configuration Management philosophy.

Comment: Thanks!! And yes, it is indeed the XY problem. I guess I have another question about this, since I have a `definition` method that I need to call based on `if ::File.exists?(...)` ... but since it isn't a resource it doesnt have `not_if` guards support. (any guidance here much appreciated=

Comment: What about exposing your real overall problem instead ?

Comment: For your definition problem,  turn it into a custom_resource or LWRP and you'll have the guard syntax inherited